# VirtualMIn Failed to detect operating system on Amazon Linux AMI release 2013.03

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2

I've just done a fresh install of Amazon Linux AMI release 2013.03 on CentOS and run VirtualMIn as follows

```
wget http://software.virtualmin.com/gpl/scripts/install.sh
sudo sh install.sh
```

but I get an error

Failed to detect operating system

```
cat /etc/issue

Amazon Linux AMI release 2013.03
Kernel \r on an \m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Linux is not a [supported operating system for VirtualMin](http://www.virtualmin.com/os-support). You should expect breakage if you attempt to use this distribution.

The specific problem here is that only a previous version of Amazon Linux (2012.03) is supported by VirtualMin (and as Grade B), which Amazon no longer supports. This makes it Grade N, not supported by the installer.

To resolve the issue, use an operating system listed by VirtualMin as Grade A Supported.

Comment: so only solution avoid using Amazon Linux?

Comment: Yes, fortunately. I have not been impressed by Amazon Linux anyway. It doesn't seem to be very high quality.

Comment: Thanks i also feel the same; should stick to A Grades distributions